# Django + MongoDB deployment on alwaysdata

Tags: python, django, mongodb, web-hosting, pymongo

I am trying to deploy [DjanMon](https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon) on [mongotest.alwaysdata.net](http://mongotest.alwaysdata.net) which uses Django and MongoDB directly without using any database engine just Pymongo.

An error sprang up while deployment. There is no Pymongo which is the driver for MongoDB for python. How do I install that or get that installed on that server?

Apart from that is there anywhere a tutorial on what settings should i use to run MongoDB with Django. I can't understand which engine to provide in database in the settings.py for mongodb.

Also is there any tutorial on how to deploy a Django Website that uses MongoDB on a cloud/ webhost?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell on the server with appropriate permissions, you can install PyMongo just like any other Python package. Either:

```
easy_install pymongo
```

or

```
pip install pymongo
```

(Either of these commands might also need `sudo` in front, depending on permissions and whether you're using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv))

Comment: ya that i tried i should have mentioned that... but that threw a denial of permission error

Comment: Have you tried installing virtualenv and installing pymongo into that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
PYTHONPATH=~/modules easy_install-2.6 --install-dir ~/modules <module>
```

http://sydlife.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/how-to-install-python-packages-in-alwaysdata-com-web-hosting/

http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Installer_un_module_Python#Installation (Official, in French)